# Android Google Maps Route Between 2 Points

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to to display route between 2 point, but it seems that its tougher than I though, although there are enough posts on the subject.

[image]

This is the code I have

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{

    private GoogleMap mMap;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    }

@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Context context;
        LatLng Current = new LatLng(55.0567842,-1.599155200000041);
        LatLng Target = new LatLng(55.0239304,-1.5453314000000091);

        LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        boundsBuilder.include(Current);
        boundsBuilder.include(Target);

        LatLngBounds bounds = boundsBuilder.build();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 3));

        PolylineOptions polyOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polyOptions.color(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
        polyOptions.width(10);
        polyOptions.add(Current, Target);




    }
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Check out this awesome easy to use library [Google-Directions-Android](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android)

Comment: Thanks @VipulAsri - I have not been developing for long and not sure how to import this library into Android Studio.

Comment: Mark this tutorial will help you for sure https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-draw-path-two-points-using-google-directions-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: Try to use Polylines. I deleted my answer because it was just a line between two points but not a route...

Comment: That would have done.

Comment: Do you want me to write it again?

Comment: @MorZa I have updated the question - but still no luck.

Comment: What does it write to you? I would try to put it in onCreate just to check if the code is working, maybe onMapReady is not called?

Comment: @MorZa Tried this and no luck - when run the map displays but no route.